# How make for obtain a SOAPPart in Axis 1.4?

Tags: java, axis, jax-rpc, java-5

My code:

```
    try {
        String endpoint = "http://alsb3-soa:80/Numero";         
        Service service = new Service();

        Call call = (Call) service.createCall();

        MessageContext message = call.getMessageContext();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = message.getMessage();
        SOAPPart sp = (SOAPPart) soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
        SOAPEnvelope env = (SOAPEnvelope) sp.getEnvelope();



        } catch (Exception e) {
          logger.error("Error: " +  e.getMessage());
        }
```

**NullPointException in Line** - SOAPEnvelope env = (SOAPEnvelope) sp.getEnvelope();

**Because this line** - SOAPMessage soapMessage = message.getMessage();

This line it's returning an object null

My WSDL

```
<WL5G3N2:definitions targetNamespace="http://www.vivo.com.br/SN/Numero"><WL5G3N0:Policy WL5G3N1:Id="encrypt-custom-body-element-and-username-token"><wssp:Identity><wssp:SupportedTokens><wssp:SecurityToken TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#UsernameToken"><wssp:UsePassword Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText"/></wssp:SecurityToken></wssp:SupportedTokens></wssp:Identity></WL5G3N0:Policy><wsp:UsingPolicy WL5G3N2:Required="true"/><WL5G3N2:types><s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.vivo.com.br/MC/Sigan"><s:include schemaLocation="http://alsb3-soa:80/Numero?SCHEMA%2FModeloCanonico%2FXSD%2FSigan%2FNumero"/><s:include schemaLocation="http://alsb3-soa:80/Numero?SCHEMA%2FModeloCanonico%2FXSD%2FSigan%2FPesquisaNumero"/><s:include schemaLocation="http://alsb3-soa:80/Numero?SCHEMA%2FModeloCanonico%2FXSD%2FSigan%2FLocalidade"/><s:element name="PesquisaNumero" type="sig:PesquisaNumero"/><s:element name="Localidade" type="sig:Localidade"/><s:element name="Numero" type="sig:Numero"/></s:schema><s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.vivo.com.br/MC/Portabilidade"><s:include schemaLocation="http://alsb3-soa:80/Numero?SCHEMA%2FModeloCanonico%2FXSD%2FPortabilidade%2FPortabilidade"/></s:schema><s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.vivo.com.br/ConsultarOperadoraNumero/"><s:include schemaLocation="http://alsb3-soa:80/Numero?SCHEMA%2FCNV2%2FREQUEST%2FAPI%2FConsultarOperadoraNumero%2FProduct%2FProduct%2FProduct"/><s:element name="Product" type="rprod:Product"/></s:schema><s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.vivo.com.br/SN/Numero"><s:import namespace="http://www.vivo.com.br/MC/Geral" schemaLocation="http://alsb3-soa:80/Numero?SCHEMA%2FModeloCanonico%2FXSD%2FGeral%2FCabecalhoVivo"/><s:import namespace="http://www.vivo.com.br/MC/Geral" schemaLocation="http://alsb3-soa:80/Numero?SCHEMA%2FModeloCanonico%2FXSD%2FGeral%2FErroInfo"/><s:include schemaLocation="http://alsb3-soa:80/Numero?SCHEMA%2FServicosNegocio%2FNumero%2FXSD%2FParametrosBuscarListaNumerosDisponiveis"/><s:include schemaLocation="http://alsb3-soa:80/Numero?SCHEMA%2FServicosNegocio%2FNumero%2FXSD%2FParametrosReservarNumero"/><s:include schemaLocation="http://alsb3-soa:80/Numero?SCHEMA%2FServicosNegocio%2FNumero%2FXSD%2FParametroAtualizarStatusNumero"/><s:include schemaLocation="http://alsb3-soa:80/Numero?SCHEMA%2FServicosNegocio%2FNumero%2FXSD%2FParametroConsultarDadosNumero"/><s:include schemaLocation="http://alsb3-soa:80/Numero?SCHEMA%2FServicosNegocio%2FNumero%2FXSD%2FParametroCriarNumeroPortabilidade"/><s:include schemaLocation="http://alsb3-soa:80/Numero?SCHEMA%2FServicosNegocio%2FNumero%2FXSD%2FParametrosBuscareReservarNumeros"/><s:include schemaLocation="http://alsb3-soa:80/Numero?SCHEMA%2FServicosNegocio%2FNumero%2FXSD%2FParametrosRecuperarEOTPorCNL"/><s:include schemaLocation="http://alsb3-soa:80/Numero?SCHEMA%2FServicosNegocio%2FNumero%2FXSD%2FResultadoReservarNumero"/><s:include schemaLocation="http://alsb3-soa:80/Numero?SCHEMA%2FServicosNegocio%2FNumero%2FXSD%2FResultadoConsultarDadosNumero"/><s:include schemaLocation="http://alsb3-soa:80/Numero?SCHEMA%2FServicosNegocio%2FNumero%2FXSD%2FResultadoBuscareReservarNumero"/><s:include schemaLocation="http://alsb3-soa:80/Numero?SCHEMA%2FServicosNegocio%2FNumero%2FXSD%2FResultadoConsultarOperadoraNumero"/><s:include schemaLocation="http://alsb3-soa:80/Numero?SCHEMA%2FServicosNegocio%2FNumero%2FXSD%2FParametrosBuscarDDDPorCNL"/><s:include schemaLocation="http://alsb3-soa:80/Numero?SCHEMA%2FServicosNegocio%2FNumero%2FXSD%2FParametrosAtualizarNumeroFixo"/><s:include schemaLocation="http://alsb3-soa:80/Numero?SCHEMA%2FServicosNegocio%2FNumero%2FXSD%2FResultadoAtualizarNumeroFixo"/><s:include schemaLocation="http://alsb3-soa:80/Numero?SCHEMA%2FServicosNegocio%2FNumero%2FXSD%2FParametrosConsultarNumeroEncaminhamento"/><s:include schemaLocation="http://alsb3-soa:80/Numero?SCHEMA%2FServicosNegocio%2FNumero%2FXSD%2FResultadoConsultarNumeroEncaminhamento"/><s:element name="buscarListaNumerosDisponiveisRequest" type="snn:ParametrosBuscarListaNumerosDisponiveis"/><s:element name="reservarNumeroRequest" type="snn:ParametrosReservarNumero"/><s:element name="reservarNumeroResponse" type="snn:ResultadoReservarNumero"/><s:element name="atualizarStatusNumeroRequest" type="snn:ParametroAtualizarStatusNumero"/><s:element name="atualizarStatusNumeroResponse"/><s:element name="consultarDadosNumeroRequest" type="snn:ParametroConsultarDadosNumero"/><s:element name="consultarDadosNumeroResponse" type="snn:ResultadoConsultarDadosNumero"/><s:element name="criarNumeroPortabilidadeRequest" type="snn:ParametroCriarNumeroPortabilidade"/><s:element name="criarNumeroPortabilidadeResponse"/><s:element name="buscareReservarNumeroRequest" type="snn:ParametrosBuscareReservarNumeros"/><s:element name="buscareReservarNumeroResponse" type="snn:ResultadoBuscareReservarNumero"/><s:element name="recuperarEOTPorCNLRequest" type="snn:ParametrosRecuperarEOTPorCNL"/><s:element name="consultarOperadoraNumeroResponse" type="snn:ResultadoConsultarOperadoraNumero"/><s:element name="buscarDDDPorCNLRequest" type="snn:ParametrosBuscarDDDPorCNL"/><s:element name="atualizarNumeroFixoRequest" type="snn:ParametrosAtualizarNumeroFixo"/><s:element name="atualizarNumeroFixoResponse" type="snn:ResultadoAtualizarNumeroFixo"/><s:element name="consultarNumeroEncaminhamentoRequest" type="snn:ParametrosConsultarNumeroEncaminhamento"/><s:element name="consultarNumeroEncaminhamentoResponse" type="snn:ResultadoConsultarNumeroEncaminhamento"/></s:schema></WL5G3N2:types><WL5G3N2:message name="erroInfoFault"><WL5G3N2:part element="WL5G3N3:erroInfo" name="erroInfo"/></WL5G3N2:message><WL5G3N2:message name="cabecalhoVIVO"><WL5G3N2:part element="WL5G3N3:cabecalhoVivo" name="cabecalhoVIVO"/></WL5G3N2:message><WL5G3N2:message name="atualizarStatusNumeroResponse"><WL5G3N2:part element="WL5G3N4:atualizarStatusNumeroResponse" name="atualizarStatusNumeroResponse"/></WL5G3N2:message><WL5G3N2:message name="atualizarStatusNumeroRequest"><WL5G3N2:part element="WL5G3N4:atualizarStatusNumeroRequest" name="atualizarStatusNumeroRequest"/></WL5G3N2:message><WL5G3N2:message name="reservarNumeroResponse"><WL5G3N2:part element="WL5G3N4:reservarNumeroResponse" name="reservarNumeroResponse"/></WL5G3N2:message><WL5G3N2:message name="buscarListaNumerosDisponiveisRequest"><WL5G3N2:part element="WL5G3N4:buscarListaNumerosDisponiveisRequest" name="buscarListaNumerosDisponiveisRequest"/></WL5G3N2:message><WL5G3N2:message name="reservarNumeroRequest"><WL5G3N2:part element="WL5G3N4:reservarNumeroRequest" name="reservarNumeroRequest"/></WL5G3N2:message><WL5G3N2:message name="PesquisaNumero"><WL5G3N2:part element="WL5G3N5:PesquisaNumero" name="PesquisaNumero"/></WL5G3N2:message><WL5G3N2:message name="consultarDadosNumeroRequest"><WL5G3N2:part element="WL5G3N4:consultarDadosNumeroRequest" name="consultarDadosNumeroRequest"/></WL5G3N2:message><WL5G3N2:message name="consultarDadosNumeroResponse"><WL5G3N2:part element="WL5G3N4:consultarDadosNumeroResponse" name="consultarDadosNumeroResponse"/></WL5G3N2:message><WL5G3N2:message name="criarNumeroPortabilidadeRequest"><WL5G3N2:part element="WL5G3N4:criarNumeroPortabilidadeRequest" name="criarNumeroPortabilidadeRequest"/></WL5G3N2:message><WL5G3N2:message name="criarNumeroPortabilidadeResponse"><WL5G3N2:part element="WL5G3N4:criarNumeroPortabilidadeResponse" name="criarNumeroPortabilidadeResponse"/></WL5G3N2:message><WL5G3N2:message name="buscareReservarNumeroRequest"><WL5G3N2:part element="WL5G3N4:buscareReservarNumeroRequest" name="buscareReservarNumeroRequest"/></WL5G3N2:message><WL5G3N2:message name="buscareReservarNumeroResponse"><WL5G3N2:part element="WL5G3N4:buscareReservarNumeroResponse" name="buscareReservarNumeroResponse"/></WL5G3N2:message><WL5G3N2:message name="recuperarEOTPorCNLRequest"><WL5G3N2:part element="WL5G3N4:recuperarEOTPorCNLRequest" name="recuperarEOTPorCNLRequest"/></WL5G3N2:message><WL5G3N2:message name="Localidade"><WL5G3N2:part element="WL5G3N5:Localidade" name="Localidade"/></WL5G3N2:message><WL5G3N2:message name="Numero"><WL5G3N2:part element="WL5G3N5:Numero" name="Numero"/></WL5G3N2:message><WL5G3N2:message name="Product"><WL5G3N2:part element="WL5G3N6:Product" name="Product"/></WL5G3N2:message><WL5G3N2:message name="consultarOperadoraNumeroResponse"><WL5G3N2:part element="WL5G3N4:consultarOperadoraNumeroResponse" name="consultarOperadoraNumeroResponse"/></WL5G3N2:message><WL5G3N2:message name="buscarDDDPorCNLRequest"><WL5G3N2:part element="WL5G3N4:buscarDDDPorCNLRequest" name="buscarDDDPorCNLRequest"/></WL5G3N2:message><WL5G3N2:message name="atualizarNumeroFixoRequest"><WL5G3N2:part element="WL5G3N4:atualizarNumeroFixoRequest" name="atualizarNumeroFixoRequest"/></WL5G3N2:message><WL5G3N2:message name="atualizarNumeroFixoResponse"><WL5G3N2:part element="WL5G3N4:atualizarNumeroFixoResponse" name="atualizarNumeroFixoResponse"/></WL5G3N2:message><WL5G3N2:message name="consultarNumeroEncaminhamentoRequest"><WL5G3N2:part element="WL5G3N4:consultarNumeroEncaminhamentoRequest" name="consultarNumeroEncaminhamentoRequest"/></WL5G3N2:message><WL5G3N2:message name="consultarNumeroEncaminhamentoResponse"><WL5G3N2:part element="WL5G3N4:consultarNumeroEncaminhamentoResponse" name="consultarNumeroEncaminhamentoResponse"/></WL5G3N2:message><WL5G3N2:portType name="NumeroSOAP"><WL5G3N2:operation name="buscarListaNumerosDisponiveis"><WL5G3N2:documentation></WL5G3N2:documentation><WL5G3N2:input message="WL5G3N4:buscarListaNumerosDisponiveisRequest"/><WL5G3N2:output message="WL5G3N4:PesquisaNumero"/><WL5G3N2:fault message="WL5G3N4:erroInfoFault" name="erroInfoFault"/></WL5G3N2:operation><WL5G3N2:operation name="reservarNumero"><WL5G3N2:documentation></WL5G3N2:documentation><WL5G3N2:input message="WL5G3N4:reservarNumeroRequest"/><WL5G3N2:output message="WL5G3N4:reservarNumeroResponse"/><WL5G3N2:fault message="WL5G3N4:erroInfoFault" name="erroInfoFault"/></WL5G3N2:operation><WL5G3N2:operation name="atualizarStatusNumero"><WL5G3N2:documentation></WL5G3N2:documentation><WL5G3N2:input message="WL5G3N4:atualizarStatusNumeroRequest"/><WL5G3N2:output message="WL5G3N4:atualizarStatusNumeroResponse"/><WL5G3N2:fault message="WL5G3N4:erroInfoFault" name="erroInfoFault"/></WL5G3N2:operation><WL5G3N2:operation name="consultarDadosNumero"><WL5G3N2:documentation></WL5G3N2:documentation><WL5G3N2:input message="WL5G3N4:consultarDadosNumeroRequest"/><WL5G3N2:output message="WL5G3N4:consultarDadosNumeroResponse"/><WL5G3N2:fault message="WL5G3N4:erroInfoFault" name="erroInfoFault"/></WL5G3N2:operation><WL5G3N2:operation name="criarNumeroPortabilidade"><WL5G3N2:documentation></WL5G3N2:documentation><WL5G3N2:input message="WL5G3N4:criarNumeroPortabilidadeRequest"/><WL5G3N2:output message="WL5G3N4:criarNumeroPortabilidadeResponse"/><WL5G3N2:fault message="WL5G3N4:erroInfoFault" name="erroInfoFault"/></WL5G3N2:operation><WL5G3N2:operation name="buscareReservarNumero"><WL5G3N2:documentation></WL5G3N2:documentation><WL5G3N2:input message="WL5G3N4:buscareReservarNumeroRequest"/><WL5G3N2:output message="WL5G3N4:buscareReservarNumeroResponse"/><WL5G3N2:fault message="WL5G3N4:erroInfoFault" name="erroInfoFault"/></WL5G3N2:operation><WL5G3N2:operation name="recuperarEOTPorCNL"><WL5G3N2:documentation></WL5G3N2:documentation><WL5G3N2:input message="WL5G3N4:recuperarEOTPorCNLRequest"/><WL5G3N2:output message="WL5G3N4:Localidade"/><WL5G3N2:fault message="WL5G3N4:erroInfoFault" name="erroInfoFault"/></WL5G3N2:operation><WL5G3N2:operation name="consultarOperadoraNumero"><WL5G3N2:documentation></WL5G3N2:documentation><WL5G3N2:input message="WL5G3N4:Product"/><WL5G3N2:output message="WL5G3N4:consultarOperadoraNumeroResponse"/><WL5G3N2:fault message="WL5G3N4:erroInfoFault" name="erroInfoFault"/></WL5G3N2:operation><WL5G3N2:operation name="buscarDDDPorCNL"><WL5G3N2:documentation></WL5G3N2:documentation><WL5G3N2:input message="WL5G3N4:buscarDDDPorCNLRequest"/><WL5G3N2:output message="WL5G3N4:Localidade"/><WL5G3N2:fault message="WL5G3N4:erroInfoFault" name="erroInfoFault"/></WL5G3N2:operation><WL5G3N2:operation name="atualizarNumeroFixo"><WL5G3N2:documentation></WL5G3N2:documentation><WL5G3N2:input message="WL5G3N4:atualizarNumeroFixoRequest"/><WL5G3N2:output message="WL5G3N4:atualizarNumeroFixoResponse"/><WL5G3N2:fault message="WL5G3N4:erroInfoFault" name="erroInfoFault"/></WL5G3N2:operation><WL5G3N2:operation name="consultarNumeroEncaminhamento"><WL5G3N2:documentation></WL5G3N2:documentation><WL5G3N2:input message="WL5G3N4:consultarNumeroEncaminhamentoRequest"/><WL5G3N2:output message="WL5G3N4:consultarNumeroEncaminhamentoResponse"/><WL5G3N2:fault message="WL5G3N4:erroInfoFault" name="erroInfoFault"/></WL5G3N2:operation></WL5G3N2:portType><WL5G3N2:binding name="NumeroSOAP" type="WL5G3N4:NumeroSOAP"><WL5G3N7:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/><WL5G3N2:operation name="buscarListaNumerosDisponiveis"><WL5G3N7:operation/><WL5G3N2:input><WL5G3N7:header message="WL5G3N4:cabecalhoVIVO" part="cabecalhoVIVO" use="literal"/><wsp:Policy><wsp:PolicyReference URI="#encrypt-custom-body-element-and-username-token"/></wsp:Policy><WL5G3N7:body parts="buscarListaNumerosDisponiveisRequest" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:input><WL5G3N2:output><WL5G3N7:body parts="PesquisaNumero" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:output><WL5G3N2:fault name="erroInfoFault"><WL5G3N7:fault name="erroInfoFault" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:fault></WL5G3N2:operation><WL5G3N2:operation name="reservarNumero"><WL5G3N7:operation/><WL5G3N2:input><WL5G3N7:header message="WL5G3N4:cabecalhoVIVO" part="cabecalhoVIVO" use="literal"/><wsp:Policy><wsp:PolicyReference URI="#encrypt-custom-body-element-and-username-token"/></wsp:Policy><WL5G3N7:body parts="reservarNumeroRequest" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:input><WL5G3N2:output><WL5G3N7:body parts="reservarNumeroResponse" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:output><WL5G3N2:fault name="erroInfoFault"><WL5G3N7:fault name="erroInfoFault" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:fault></WL5G3N2:operation><WL5G3N2:operation name="atualizarStatusNumero"><WL5G3N7:operation/><WL5G3N2:input><WL5G3N7:header message="WL5G3N4:cabecalhoVIVO" part="cabecalhoVIVO" use="literal"/><wsp:Policy><wsp:PolicyReference URI="#encrypt-custom-body-element-and-username-token"/></wsp:Policy><WL5G3N7:body parts="atualizarStatusNumeroRequest" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:input><WL5G3N2:output><WL5G3N7:body parts="atualizarStatusNumeroResponse" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:output><WL5G3N2:fault name="erroInfoFault"><WL5G3N7:fault name="erroInfoFault" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:fault></WL5G3N2:operation><WL5G3N2:operation name="consultarDadosNumero"><WL5G3N7:operation/><WL5G3N2:input><WL5G3N7:header message="WL5G3N4:cabecalhoVIVO" part="cabecalhoVIVO" use="literal"/><wsp:Policy><wsp:PolicyReference URI="#encrypt-custom-body-element-and-username-token"/></wsp:Policy><WL5G3N7:body parts="consultarDadosNumeroRequest" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:input><WL5G3N2:output><WL5G3N7:body parts="consultarDadosNumeroResponse" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:output><WL5G3N2:fault name="erroInfoFault"><WL5G3N7:fault name="erroInfoFault" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:fault></WL5G3N2:operation><WL5G3N2:operation name="criarNumeroPortabilidade"><WL5G3N7:operation/><WL5G3N2:input><WL5G3N7:header message="WL5G3N4:cabecalhoVIVO" part="cabecalhoVIVO" use="literal"/><wsp:Policy><wsp:PolicyReference URI="#encrypt-custom-body-element-and-username-token"/></wsp:Policy><WL5G3N7:body parts="criarNumeroPortabilidadeRequest" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:input><WL5G3N2:output><WL5G3N7:body parts="criarNumeroPortabilidadeResponse" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:output><WL5G3N2:fault name="erroInfoFault"><WL5G3N7:fault name="erroInfoFault" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:fault></WL5G3N2:operation><WL5G3N2:operation name="buscareReservarNumero"><WL5G3N7:operation/><WL5G3N2:input><WL5G3N7:header message="WL5G3N4:cabecalhoVIVO" part="cabecalhoVIVO" use="literal"/><wsp:Policy><wsp:PolicyReference URI="#encrypt-custom-body-element-and-username-token"/></wsp:Policy><WL5G3N7:body parts="buscareReservarNumeroRequest" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:input><WL5G3N2:output><WL5G3N7:body parts="buscareReservarNumeroResponse" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:output><WL5G3N2:fault name="erroInfoFault"><WL5G3N7:fault name="erroInfoFault" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:fault></WL5G3N2:operation><WL5G3N2:operation name="recuperarEOTPorCNL"><WL5G3N7:operation/><WL5G3N2:input><WL5G3N7:header message="WL5G3N4:cabecalhoVIVO" part="cabecalhoVIVO" use="literal"/><wsp:Policy><wsp:PolicyReference URI="#encrypt-custom-body-element-and-username-token"/></wsp:Policy><WL5G3N7:body parts="recuperarEOTPorCNLRequest" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:input><WL5G3N2:output><WL5G3N7:body parts="Localidade" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:output><WL5G3N2:fault name="erroInfoFault"><WL5G3N7:fault name="erroInfoFault" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:fault></WL5G3N2:operation><WL5G3N2:operation name="consultarOperadoraNumero"><WL5G3N7:operation/><WL5G3N2:input><WL5G3N7:header message="WL5G3N4:cabecalhoVIVO" part="cabecalhoVIVO" use="literal"/><wsp:Policy><wsp:PolicyReference URI="#encrypt-custom-body-element-and-username-token"/></wsp:Policy><WL5G3N7:body parts="Product" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:input><WL5G3N2:output><WL5G3N7:body parts="consultarOperadoraNumeroResponse" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:output><WL5G3N2:fault name="erroInfoFault"><WL5G3N7:fault name="erroInfoFault" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:fault></WL5G3N2:operation><WL5G3N2:operation name="buscarDDDPorCNL"><WL5G3N7:operation/><WL5G3N2:input><WL5G3N7:header message="WL5G3N4:cabecalhoVIVO" part="cabecalhoVIVO" use="literal"/><wsp:Policy><wsp:PolicyReference URI="#encrypt-custom-body-element-and-username-token"/></wsp:Policy><WL5G3N7:body parts="buscarDDDPorCNLRequest" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:input><WL5G3N2:output><WL5G3N7:body parts="Localidade" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:output><WL5G3N2:fault name="erroInfoFault"><WL5G3N7:fault name="erroInfoFault" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:fault></WL5G3N2:operation><WL5G3N2:operation name="atualizarNumeroFixo"><WL5G3N7:operation/><WL5G3N2:input><WL5G3N7:header message="WL5G3N4:cabecalhoVIVO" part="cabecalhoVIVO" use="literal"/><wsp:Policy><wsp:PolicyReference URI="#encrypt-custom-body-element-and-username-token"/></wsp:Policy><WL5G3N7:body parts="atualizarNumeroFixoRequest" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:input><WL5G3N2:output><WL5G3N7:body parts="atualizarNumeroFixoResponse" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:output><WL5G3N2:fault name="erroInfoFault"><WL5G3N7:fault name="erroInfoFault" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:fault></WL5G3N2:operation><WL5G3N2:operation name="consultarNumeroEncaminhamento"><WL5G3N7:operation/><WL5G3N2:input><WL5G3N7:header message="WL5G3N4:cabecalhoVIVO" part="cabecalhoVIVO" use="literal"/><wsp:Policy><wsp:PolicyReference URI="#encrypt-custom-body-element-and-username-token"/></wsp:Policy><WL5G3N7:body parts="consultarNumeroEncaminhamentoRequest" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:input><WL5G3N2:output><WL5G3N7:body parts="consultarNumeroEncaminhamentoResponse" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:output><WL5G3N2:fault name="erroInfoFault"><WL5G3N7:fault name="erroInfoFault" use="literal"/></WL5G3N2:fault></WL5G3N2:operation></WL5G3N2:binding><WL5G3N2:service name="NumeroSOAPQSService"><WL5G3N2:port binding="WL5G3N4:NumeroSOAP" name="NumeroSOAPQSPort"><WL5G3N7:address location="http://alsb3-soa:80/Numero"/></WL5G3N2:port></WL5G3N2:service></WL5G3N2:definitions>
```

Comment: is your service up? what you are getting when you type the endpoint in browser?

Comment: <soapenv:Envelope><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault><faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode><faultstring>BEA-382033: A soap:Envelope must contain a soap:Body</faultstring><detail><con:fault><con:errorCode>BEA-382033</con:errorCode><con:reason>A soap:Envelope must contain a soap:Body</con:reason><con:location><con:path>request-pipeline</con:path></con:location></con:fault></detail></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: can you edit your question and put your wsdl.? I might be able to help

Comment: or what is the method name of your service?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some work to do here..

I will tell you a silly mistake you are doing. You are not setting the endpoint to your service object. So the service object doesn't know which endpoint to hit.

It should be something like

```
URL enpoint = new URL("http://alsb3-soa:80/Numero");
Service service = new Service();
Call call = (Call) service.createCall();
call.setTargetEndpointAddress(enpoint);
```

now call any of the method available at your endpoint(operation in your wsdl). And pass an object of the type input(input message of that operation in your wsdl)

```
RequestObject ro = new RequestObject();
Object[] args = new Object[1];
args[0] = ro; 
Object result = call.invoke("somemethod", args);
```

You might want to start with a small example to begin with. Check this [link](http://www.javabeat.net/2007/07/programming-web-services-using-apache-axis/)